# In the figure below demonstrate the give expression as a function of $ r $

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{ac}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}=?$

In the figure, $I$ is the incenter of the triangle $ABC$ , $a$ and $b$ are maximal, and $r$ is the inradius of the triangle $MNI$.

[image]

I try

$a$(max) and $b$(max) implies a and b are at the midpoints of $AB$ and $BC$

$\triangle AJK_{(right)}:OM = c-a: ON = c-b $

$MN^2 = (c-a)^2+(c-b)^2 \implies MN^2 = c^2-2ca+a^2+c^2-2bc+b^2=2(c^2+a^2-ac-bc)$

$\triangle AFO: AF^2=c^2-(c-2a)^2\implies AF =2\sqrt{ac-a^2}$

$\triangle OHC: CH^2=c^2-(c-2b)^2\implies CH =2\sqrt{bc-b^2}$

[image]

Comment: I am confused because the equation is not dimensionally co sistent; it does not hold if $r,a,b,c$ are multiplied by a scale factor $\lambda$. Is there a mistake or do we have an assumed unit segment?

Comment: @OscarLanzi The question is transcribed faithfully

Comment: Without a defined unit segment I cannot see how thus question os well posed. Sorry.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  No probeem. Really, the way it is, the units of a lad do not correspond to the units of another. I will try with  $\frac{2}{r}$

Comment: Can anyone find this relationship? Maybe the solution is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{r.b}}$

Answer (score 1):

I will use $\alpha, \beta,\gamma;\rho$ instead of the values $a,b,c;r$ from the statement above, since i have a better usage for the good old latin letters.

The solution below is analytic, i saw no striking geometric property of $\rho$ that would allow a simple computation for this length.

---

We will place the given triangle $\Delta ABC$ with two vertices
$A=(4a,0)$ and $B=(0,4b)$ on the cartesian axes. Its right angle is in $C=(0,0)$. The factor four appears in order to minimize typing denominators. So the sides of $\Delta ABC$ have lengths $4a$, $4b$, and $4c$, connected by the usual pythagorean identity
$$
c^2 = a^2+b^2\ .
$$
**We will use $a,b,c$ (and later $r$) with this meaning only.**

[image: mse problem 4704273]

Then $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ have immediate formulas in terms of $a,b,c$:
$$
\begin{aligned} 
\alpha &= c-b\ ,\\
\beta &= c-a\ ,\\
\gamma &= 2c\ .
\end{aligned} 
$$
So we need to "relate somehow" the expression
$$
\begin{aligned} 
E 
&= 
\frac 1{\sqrt{\alpha\beta}} +
\frac 1{\sqrt{\beta\gamma}} +
\frac 1{\sqrt{\gamma\alpha}}
\\
&=
\frac 1{\sqrt{(c-a)(c-b)}} +
\frac 1{\sqrt{2c(c-a)}} +
\frac 1{\sqrt{2c(c-b)}}
\\
&=
\frac {\sqrt{(c+a)(c+b)}}{ab} +
\frac {\sqrt{2c(c+a)}}{2bc} +
\frac {\sqrt{2c(c+b)}}{2ac}
\\
&=\frac 1{2abc}\Big(\ 
2c\sqrt{(c+a)(c+b)}
+
a\sqrt{2c(c+a)}
+
b\sqrt{2c(c+b)}
\ \Big)
\\
&=\frac {\sqrt2}{2abc}\Big(\ 
c(a+b+c)
+
a\sqrt{c(c+a)}
+
b\sqrt{c(c+b)}
\ \Big)
\ .
\end{aligned} 
$$
to the length $\rho$, best solely as a function of $\rho$.

---

We will compute the distance $IJ$

- from $I=(r,r)$, the incenter of $\Delta ABC$,
- to ($J$, its projection on) $MN$.

The inradius $r$ is computed as area $\frac 12 4a\cdot 4b$ divided by half-perimeter $\frac12 (4a+4b+4c)$. This gives:
$$ r=\frac {4ab}{a+b+c}\ .$$
The cartesian equation of the line $MN$ w.r.t. the axes $CA=Ox$ and $CB=Oy$ is
$$
0=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x & y\\
1 & 2a & b-c\\
1 & a-c & 2b
\end{vmatrix}
\ .
$$
Expanding and norming to an equation of the shape $ux+vy+w=0$ with
$u^2+v^2=1$ we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
u &=(b+c)/q\ ,\\
v &=(a+c)/q\ ,\\
w &=-\det\begin{bmatrix}
2a & b-c\\
a-c & 2b
\end{bmatrix}
/q 
%= (4ab-(c-a)(c-b))/q
\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{ where}\\
q&=\sqrt{(a+c)^2+(b+c)^2}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The distance from $I$ to $MN$ is obtained by plugging in $I=(r,r)$ as $(x,y)$ inside $|ux+vy+w|$, so the height $IJ$, and the sides of $\Delta IMN$ are
determined by:
$$
\begin{aligned}
IJ &=\frac1q \Big(\ r(a+b+2c)-(3ab+ac+bc-c^2)\ \Big)\ ,\\
MN^2 &= (2c-\beta)^2 + (2c-\alpha)^2 = (a+c)^2+(b+c)^2 = q^2\ ,\\
MI^2 &= (r-2a)^2 + (r+\alpha)^2\ ,\\
NI^2 &= (r-2b)^2 + (r+\beta)^2\ .\\
&\qquad\text{ Let make these expressions explicit:}\\
MN &= q\\
&=\sqrt{c(2a+2b+3c)}
\ ,\\[3mm]
MN\cdot IJ\;(a+b+c) &= 
4ab(a+b+2c) - (a+b+c)(3ab+ac+bc-c^2)
\\
&=(4ab-3ab)(a+b+c) +4abc  -(a+b+c)c(a+b-c)\\
&=ab(a+b+c)+4abc - c((a+b)^2-c^2)\\
&=ab(a+b+c)+4abc - c(2ab)\\
&=ab(a+b+3c)\ ,\\
MI^2(a+b+c)^2 &= (4ab- 2a(a+b+c))^2 + (4ab +(c-b)(a+b+c))^2
\\
&=4a^2(a-b+c)^2 + (4ab+a(c-b)+(c^2-b^2))^2
\\
&=4a^2(a-b+c)^2 + (3ab + ac + a^2)^2
\\
&=4a^2(a-b+c)^2 + a^2(a+3b+c)^2\\
&=a^2(5a^2 - 2ab + 13b^2 + 10ac - 2bc + 5c^2)\qquad\text{ replace }b^2=c^2-a^2\\
&=a^2(-8a^2 - 2ab + 10ac - 2bc + 18c^2)\\
&=2a^2(-8a^2 - 2ab + 10ac - 2bc + 18c^2)\\
&=2a^2(a+c)(9c-4a-b)
\ ,
\\[3mm]
NI^2(a+b+c)^2 &= 2b^2(b+c)(9c-a-4b)
\ .
\\[3mm]
%
&\qquad\text{ From here we compute:}\\
\rho
&=
\frac
{\operatorname{Area}(\Delta MNI)}
{\operatorname{Halfperimeter}(\Delta MNI)}
=\frac{MN\cdot IJ/2}{(MN+MI+NI)/2}
\\
\frac 1\rho
&=
\frac
{(MN+MI+NI)(a+b+c)}{MN\cdot IJ\; (a+b+c)}
\\
&=
\frac 1{ab(a+b+3c)}
\Bigg(
(a+b+c)\sqrt{c(2a+2b+3c)}
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad +
a\sqrt{2(a+c)(9c-4a-b)} \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad +
b\sqrt{2(b+c)(9c-a-4b)} \Bigg)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
And now i cannot see how to express $E$ only in terms of $\rho$.

---

*Check:*

A picture check first, we are using the special values $a=2$, $b=3$, $c=\sqrt{13}$, and the computed value for $\rho$ is:

[image: mse problem 4704273]

---

Computer check for the numerical values in the picture, using two formulas for $\rho$, the simpler one from the start, and the more complicated one obtained after reshaping algebraically to get a final form.

```
var('a,b,c');
a1, b1, c1, r = c - b, c - a, 2*c, 4*a*b/(a + b + c)
q = sqrt( (a + c)^2 + (b + c)^2 )
IJ = 1/q * ( r*(a + b + 2*c) - (3*a*b + a*c + b*c - c^2) )
MN = q
MI = sqrt( (r - 2*a)^2 + (r + a1)^2 )
NI = sqrt( (r - 2*b)^2 + (r + b1)^2 )
rho = MN*IJ / (MN + MI + NI)
```

And the numerical values are:

```
sage: rho.subs(c=sqrt(13),a=2,b=3).n()
0.622680578874492
sage: rho_alternative = a*b*(a+b+3*c) / (
....:       (a+b+c)*sqrt(       c*(2*a+2*b+3*c) )
....:     +       a*sqrt( 2*(a+c)*(9*c-4*a-b) )
....:     +       b*sqrt( 2*(b+c)*(9*c-a-4*b) ) )
sage: rho_alternative.subs(c=sqrt(13),a=2,b=3).n()
0.622680578874491
```

---

---

Let us consider some other special situation,
$a=9$, $b=40$, $c=41$. We compute $E$ and $\rho$ in this case:

The expression $E$ is:

```
sage: E = 1/sqrt(a1*b1) + 1/sqrt(b1*c1) + 1/sqrt(c1*a1)
sage: E.subs(c=41, a=9, b=40).n()
0.306729941607559
sage: E_alternative = sqrt(2)/(2*a*b*c)*( c*(a+b+c) + a*sqrt(c*(c+a)) + b*sqrt(c*(c+b)) )
sage: E_alternative.subs(c=41, a=9, b=40).n()
0.306729941607559
sage: E_alternative.subs(c=41, a=9, b=40)
1/656*sqrt(2)*(sqrt(82) + 8*sqrt(41) + 82)
```

So in this special case
$$
E = \frac 1{656}(2\sqrt{41} + 8\sqrt{82} + 82\sqrt 2)\ .
$$

The value for $\rho$ is

```
sage: rho.subs(c=41, a=9, b=40).n()
3.57762166258648
sage: rho_alternative = a*b*(a+b+3*c) / (
....:       (a+b+c)*sqrt(       c*(2*a+2*b+3*c) )
....:     +       a*sqrt( 2*(a+c)*(9*c-4*a-b) )
....:     +       b*sqrt( 2*(b+c)*(9*c-a-4*b) ) )
sage: rho_alternative.subs(c=41, a=9, b=40).n()
3.57762166258648
sage: rho_alternative.subs(c=41, a=9, b=40)
1376/(sqrt(586)*sqrt(2) + 2*sqrt(9061) + 160)
sage: factor(586)
2 * 293
sage: factor(9061)
13 * 17 * 41
```

So
$$
\frac 1\rho
=
\frac 1{1376}(2\sqrt{293} +2\sqrt{9061} +160)\ .
$$
An algebraic formula for $E$ (in this special case) involving only $\rho$ is excluded, since we are working in a different number field.

Comment: Thanks for help